# SQL Server. How to remove NEIGHBORING duplicate records

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, duplicates

I am looking for a simple approach to remove NEIGHBORING duplicate records from a table such as this:

```
PatientID|STATE
1|A
1|A
1|B
1|B
1|C
1|A
1|C
1|C
1|B
2|A
...
```

That is, from the above I want to keep the heighest ranked letter from each block of letters of a given kind. Like this:

```
PatientID|STATE
1|A
1|B
1|C
1|A
1|C
1|B
2|A
...
```

I have no other columns available. I know about the ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY ..) functions but don't see how it can be applied here

Comment: Where does that ordering come from (the one in your first result) ? You have a date field somewhere ?  An identity field ?

Comment: If you have no other columns available, then you cannot do what you want.  SQL tables are inherently unordered.  You can do `select *` and get the results in different orders at different times.

Comment: I should have been more clear. There is an ordering of the state values for a given PatientID, which is essentially a date, but for the purpose at hand I know simply the order which I can e.g. represent by a new identity ID column

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SQL Server has the nice ability to have updatable CTEs.  Assuming you have an `id` field or datetime field to specify the ordering, you can identify the "groups" of neighboring records using a `row_number()` trick -- the difference between the row number within a given `PatientId` and within a given `PatientId, state` combination.  Then just use this group to enumerate the values and keep the first or last one:

```
with todelete as (
      select t.*, row_number() over (partition by Patientid, state, grp order by id) as seqnum
      from (select t.*,
                   (row_number() over (partition by PatientId order by id) -
                    row_number() over (partition by PatientId, state order by id)
                   ) as grp
            from table t
           ) t
    )
delete from todelete
    where seqnum > 1;
```

Comment: _"I have no other columns available. I know about the ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY ..) functions but don't see how it can be applied here"_

Comment: Aha! A very clever use of the row_number() function. This does what I was looking for. I moved it out of the CTE framework, as I will probably not actually delete the duplicates in the real implementation but allow it as filtering flags. Another thing is that I believe the Partition by in the outer select statement needs to be by (PID,state,grp) instead of by (id,state,grp)

Answer (score 0):

I think below query will help you

```
SElect PatientID,State,COUNT(*) AS TOTAL INTO #Temp2  from table  GROUP by PatientID,State
HAVING COUNT(*) > 1

DELETE FROM table 
FROM table  a INNER JOIN (
SElect PatientID,State,COUNT(*) AS TOTAL  from table   GROUP by PatientID,State
HAVING COUNT(*) > 1) b ON a.PatientID = b.PatientID AND a.State = b.State

INSERT INTO table  SELECT PatientID,State FROM #Temp2
```